# Call templated method on each element in a vector of templated objects

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

I have a sequence of task objects that I'd like to chain together such that the output from one task is the input to the next.

```
template <typename Input, typename Output> class Task {
public:
  std::function<Output(Input)> func;

  Task(std::function<Output(Input)> func) : func(func){};
  Output run(const Input& input) { return func(input); }
};
```

Great, now I can chain some tasks together.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Task.h"

int main() {
  auto func1 = [](int i) {
    return i + 1;
  };
  auto func2 = [](std::string i) {
    return stoi(i);
  };

  Task<int, int> task1(func1);
  Task<std::string, int> task2(func2);

  std::cout << task1.run(task2.run("1"));
  return 0;
}
```

But now, I'd like to put tasks in a `TaskList` container so I don't need to hardcode these chains of tasks. The API might look as follows:

```
class TaskList {
public:
  std::vector<ITask> tasks;

  void append(ITask task) { tasks.push_back(task); }
  void run() { // Run all tasks }
};
```

Where `ITask` is a base class for the various `Task<Input, Output>` types. How might I write such `ITask` and `TaskList` classes? There are many ways to shuffle where the types get introduced (e.g., `Task` constructor, `run` method), but I haven't found a way to generalize to `TaskList`.

Is this approach totally wrong? Or is what I'm trying to do bad design?

Comment: You have a problem. If you use a general container then the input/output types at each stage will be unknown at compile time. This means you'll need to store the result of each stage in a `variant` or `any` and then the next stage must coerce the variant into the correct type (or convert it, or throw)

Comment: @RichardHodges Or if the task I/O types are known at compile time, a `tuple`

Comment: Ah, I was hoping to avoid going down this path, but yes, the input / output types are unknown at compile time. I could also have a base class for all my input / output types, but that's pretty crummy since I may not have control over all types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using recursion and template specialization, instead of an `std::vector` ?

The following should be a working example

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename, typename ...>
class TaskList;

template <typename First>
class TaskList<First>
 {
   public:
      TaskList () 
       { }

      First run (First const & firstVal) const
       { return firstVal; }
 };

template <typename Output, typename Input, typename ... Prevs>
class TaskList<Output, Input, Prevs...>
 {
   private:
      std::function<Output(Input)> const  head;
      TaskList<Input, Prevs...>    const  tail;

   public:
      template <typename ... Funcs>
      TaskList (std::function<Output(Input)> const & f0,
                Funcs const & ... funcsPre)
         : head {f0}, tail {funcsPre...}
       { }

      template <typename T>
      Output run (T const & firstArg) const
       { return head(tail.run(firstArg)); }
 };

int main ()
 {
   auto func0 = [](int i) { return long(i << 1); };
   auto func1 = [](int i) { return i + 1; };
   auto func2 = [](std::string i) { return stoi(i); };

   TaskList<long, int, int, std::string> taskL012(func0, func1, func2);

   std::cout << taskL012.run("1") << std::endl; // print 4
 }
```

Comment: I think it will work. But unlike usual use of recursion and template specialization, which one normally don't exhaust the implementation limits, I think the OP might be looking for something with less restriction of how long the chain might run.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting solution! However, in addition to @YanZhou's comment, it also seems that I would need to specify the task chain at compile time. My application might be able to swing this, but I'll need to think more. Regarding `std::vector`, my fault for not mentioning in the original post; I may want random access to individual tasks to modify or swap them.

Comment: @danielsuo - You need to specify the task chain at **run** time? Wow! If so, it's a completely different scenario. You should specify this in your question and show an example of the code you want to write. You have edit privileges for you questions? If not, you should open another question or, if you can explain better, I can edit the present answer for you.

Comment: @max66: I redefined the APIs that my application will use so now I require that the task chain be specified compile time, so this works nicely, thanks! Didn't think to use recursive templates.